# SOLR Join and filter on both cores

Tags: solr

is it possible to filter on both SOLR cores that used join..

I have two cores:

First core (Person):
id
name
surname

Second core (Article):
id
person_id
title
description

and i want to get results from both where person name is like "test" and article title is like "test"

can this be done?

Example how i think it should work, but it don't: (this query shows that field title dont exists)

```
{!join from=id fromIndex=person to=person_id}(name:("test")*) OR (title:("test")*)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, with solr join you can get results only from one index.

If you need results from both then you might have to use 2 solr queries,

1. Get results from Person where (name:("test")*)
2. Get results from Article where (title:("test")*) and person_id = ids from first query.